# React Material UI CardMedia video component not playing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I see a thumbnail but no way to start or stop the video, also is there any way to have it autoplay and repeat?

https://material-ui.com/api/card-media/

```
<CardMedia
component="video"
image='/video.mp4'
title='title'
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

To show controls you need to add controls attribute to show contols on render (This is not documented, but video control in html5 we need to set `controls` attribute to show it).

Also don't forget to add style with some specific height as specified by mui documentation.
https://material-ui.com/api/card-media/#cardmedia-api

```
<CardMedia
component="video"
image='/video.mp4'
title='title'
controls
/>
```

Comment: muted and loop seem to work as well but not autoplay, any idea?

Comment: Nevermind, it's autoPlay not autoplay and it works, thanks!

Comment: specifying muted and loop in addition to autoPlay seems to work for me