# Autoplay video in react material-ui CardMedia component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, webm

I have a [Material UI Card component](https://material-ui.com/components/cards/) that I'd like to have contain a video (webm) that autoplays.  (It's a mute video)

The documentation for the [CardMedia component](https://material-ui.com/api/card-media/) indicates to list any HTML element as the component element type -- so I have listed "video".

I have tried playing with suggestions from here: [Video autoplay not working - Trying to find a fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259734/video-autoplay-not-working-trying-to-find-a-fix/52542831)

Specifically, I've tried added `component: 'video autoPlay muted` to no avail - getting an error that the element cannot be created.  I also tried passing an actual tag: `<video autoPlay muted>`... also failure ('expecting string').

```
<Card className={classes.root} raised={true}>
        <CardHeader
            title={camera.cameraName}
        />

        <CardActionArea>
            <CardMedia
                component='video'
                className={classes.media}
                image={"path/to/file/video.webm"}
            />
            <CardContent>

                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                    Some Text
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
        </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
```

Any suggestions on how I can get a video to auto play in a MaterialUI CardMedia component?

Alternatively, I'd settle for simply having the controls show up by default - as is, you have to right click and select 'show controls'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[React Material UI CardMedia video component not playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62686132/react-material-ui-cardmedia-video-component-not-playing) led me to the idea that CardMedia appears to simply pass on properties to the 'parent' component (a  tag, in this case)

As such, I was able to add an 'autoPlay' property to the CardMedia and it worked.

```
        <CardMedia
            component='video'
            className={classes.media}
            image={"path/to/file/video.webm"}
            autoPlay
        />
```

Note that adding 'controls' also added controls to the video.

Comment: can we use youtube link here and is there any other way to manage video in MUI

Answer (score 4):

Also, in case it's helpful to others when using an iframe component, you can set `allow="autoPlay"` combined with `?autoplay=1&mute` in the URL and it will work:

```html
<CardMedia component="iframe" src={video} allow="autoPlay"/>
```